# How can we scroll the ListView in tablet using Android

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

In the development phase of an application i got strucked with one place that, scrolling...

In the application i have two `ListView` items for listing some different data. In that my List can display n no.of items. If i have a Single `ListView`means i will use the 'ScrollView' for the full screen..

In this How can i implement this?

My code is,..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Average"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/average"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Maximum"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maximum"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Minimum"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/minmum"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="437dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="30dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Top Students List"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="302dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="30dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Bottom Students List"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="302dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here i tried the Scrollbar in the 'ListView' as,..

```
 <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="302dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" >
 </ListView>
```

It works in my System, while developing, but in tablet i couldn't Scroll it,.. Because in my PC i used my Mouse's Scroller to do that activity, but in Tablet no option for that...

Give me Yours Suggestion for scrolling down my 'ListView', it needs to display only 4 List items once.. The others items will be shown while performing the Scroll function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just Remove the `ScrollView`ScrollView from the XML file. Because the `ListView` defaultly have the charcteristic for scrolling down..

So My New Code is,..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Average"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/average"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Maximum"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maximum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Minimum"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minmum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="437dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Top Students List"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="302dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Bottom Students List"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="302dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And its Working...